# RubyMine, how to write a message to RSpec log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I would like know please, how to log simple messages into RSpec log ? or any log that I can see into the RubyMine IDE ?

I have seen http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/
is this the right way to log messages ? is there a simple way or example ?
I know, it should be easy, as in Visual Studio, I just Console.write ("my message ..")

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it:

```
Rails.logger.info('My message ...')
```